# Appended JavaScript object to form data is always received as null on server

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

On frontend (appending image file, and JavaScript object with details about product):

```
 let f = new FormData();
 f.append('File', file);

 objectToSend = {
    ...values
 };

f.append('ProductDto', objectToSend );

await createProduct(f);

export const createProduct = async data => {
  return axiosWrapper.request({
    url: `/products`,
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
  });
};
```

On backend (receiving appended data as FromForm):

```
// POST: api/products
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm]ProductFile file)
{
 // Create product
}
```

`ProductFile` class looks like this:

```
public class ProductFile
{
   public IFormFile File { get; set; }
   public ProductDTO ProductDto{ get; set; } 
}
```

Issue is that `ProductDto` is always null, while `File` is populated as it should be.. I don't understand why is that ?

P.S I've tried appending it like this also:

```
f.append('ProductDto', JSON.stringify(objectToSend));
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are appending an object in FormData. Form data accepts key-value pairs where the value is expected to be a string as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

Try converting the object to a string first

```
f.append('ProductDto', JSON.stringify(objectToSend) );
```

Then in your backend, before accessing it, convert it back to an object.

Comment: I've tried that also earlier, and still it's null when I hover mouse my property before accessing it..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the content-type of the request is formdata so ASPNET uses a FormData Model Binder to populate the properties of the model. This model binder won't be able to deserialize the json and bind it to the model.

If you want the model binder to be able to set the values of the properties of you object they need to be defined as formdata in your request.

For exemple if your object as a structure like this :

```cs
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

You'll need to do :

```js
f.append('ProductDto.ProductId', objectToSend.productId );
f.append('ProductDto.Name', objectToSend.name);
```

Another solution is to use a string in your model, and deserialize the DTO yourself :

```cs
public class ProductFile
{
   public IFormFile File { get; set; }
   public string ProductDto { get; set; } 
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm]ProductFile file)
{
    var productDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductDTO>(file.ProductDto);
}
```

Comment: So I have to fill all ProductDTO properties?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro If you want to use the FormDataModelBinder yes all properties must be included in the form data.
You can do it with something like :
```for (let key of Object.keys(objectToSend)) f.append('ProductDto.' + key, objectToSend[key]);```
But this will only work if your object doesn't have complex properties